# jQuery UI AutoComplete - How to handle multiple values ,when user removes a value in between the selected values

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-ui, autocomplete, jquery-ui-autocomplete

**This is What I have :**

I have a text box input element as below for loading cities autoloaded and a hidden field to list its ids:

```
<label class="col-sm-2 control-label" for="city_disp"> City</label>
<div class="col-sm-5">
  <div class="input-group">
    <input type="hidden" class="hidden_value" name="city" id="city" value="" />
    <input type="text" name="city_disp" placeholder="City" 
        id="city_disp" data-request_type="cities" value=""
        class="form-control autocomplete-input-field" autocomplete="off" />
  </div>
</div>
```

**jQuery UI AutoComplete which I use, the data array comes from Ajax response  :**

```
            function split( val ) {
                        return val.split( /,\s*/ );
            }
            function extractLast( term ) {
                        return split( term ).pop();
            }

            $(".autocomplete-input-field").autocomplete({
                     source: function (request, response) {
                                     $this = this.element;
                                     var term = extractLast(request.term);
                                     $.ajax({
                                              url: myHome+'/my_ajax',
                                              dataType: "json",
                                              type: "POST",
                                              data: {
                                                      term: term,
                                                      action_type: "getdata"
                                               },
                                               success: function (data) {
                                                                    response(data);
                                               }
                                   });
                     },
            minLength: 2,
            select: function (event, ui) {
                      var tempval =  $(this).val() ;
                      var terms = split( this.value );
                      var split_string = split( 
                      $(this).closest('div').find('.hidden_value').val() );
                      split_string.pop();
                      terms.pop();
                      terms.push( ui.item.label );
                      split_string.push( ui.item.value );
                      terms.push( "" );
                      split_string.push( "" );
                      var labels = terms.join( ", " );
                      var new_vals = split_string.join( "," );
                      $(this).val(labels);
                      $(this).closest('div').find('.hidden_value').val(new_vals);
                      return false;
                     },
                      focus: function (event, ui) {
                                  event.preventDefault();
                      }
            });
```

**Output I am getting currently:**

Currently,autocomplete is working fine when I type atleast 2 characters in the text box **name="city_disp"** . If user selects 3 values from the autocomplete cities list: 'New York,Washington,London' and the ids corresponding to these cities '45,56,78' gets appended to the hidden html input field **name="city"**.

**Modification which I am trying to implement :**

Suppose if user selects 'New York,Washington,London' and its id gets  '45,56,78' gets appended to the hidden html input field **name="city"**. and the user removes a Washington from the selected values . Then the hidden value must also change accordingly to '45,78'. Also when a user omits Washington to some absurd characters like 'dasdsad' ,then how to handle such situations with this jQuery UI AutoComplete?

Comment: Why not delay the collection of the selected values until the hidden value is needed? I suppose it is submitted with the form? Could you not do this task on submission?

Comment: It would be good if its handled using jquery itself so as to be user friendly and not to accept any typo errors from the user

Comment: Sure, but that doesn't answer my suggestion. On submission you can execute JavaScript.

Comment: You might consider setting up an Array of Objects that can store the selected IDs and Names. This way when a item is removed, the corresponding element in the Array can be removed. Then, when the Form is submitted, the IDs can be added back to the Form Data or add to an element.

Answer (score 0):

There is not a good way to do this with two unique lists of text. there becomes no relationship between the two except for the positioning. When the User removes and item from List A, how do you identify in List B the change, and align the lists.

Consider moving the selected items to a new User interface with the ID attached.

Example: https://jsfiddle.net/Twisty/m3vfk0hg/

**HTML**

```
<label class="col-sm-2 control-label" for="city_disp"> City</label>
<div class="col-sm-5">
  <div class="input-group">
    <input type="hidden" class="hidden_value" name="city" id="city" />
    <input type="text" name="city_disp" placeholder="City" id="city_disp" data-request_type="cities" class="form-control autocomplete-input-field" autocomplete="off" />
  </div>
  <div class="selected"></div>
</div>
```

Mostly the same HTML, yet now we have a section to display the Selected items, after they have been selected.

**CSS**

```
.selected {
  margin: 3px;
}

.selected-item {
  border: 1px solid #00f;
  border-radius: 6px;
  padding: 3px;
  background: #ccf;
  margin: 3px;
}

.selected-item .btn-close {
  margin-left: 6px;
}
```

Giving us some Style.

**JavaScript**

```
$(function() {

  var myAutoData = [{
      label: "New York",
      value: "45"
    }, {
      label: "Washington",
      value: "56"
    },
    {
      label: "London",
      value: "78"
    }
  ];

  function newItem(it) {
    var item = $("<span>", {
      class: "selected-item",
      "data-id": it.value
    }).html(it.label);
    $("<span>", {
      class: "btn-close"
    }).appendTo(item);
    if ($("#city").val().length > 0) {
      $("#city").val($("#city").val() + "," + it.value);
    } else {
      $("#city").val(it.value);
    }
    return item;
  }

  $(".autocomplete-input-field").autocomplete({
    source: function(request, response) {
      var term = request.term;
      $.ajax({
        url: "/echo/json/",
        dataType: "json",
        type: "POST",
        data: {
          json: JSON.stringify(myAutoData),
          term: term
        },
        success: function(data) {
          response(data);
        }
      });
    },
    minLength: 2,
    select: function(event, ui) {
      $(this).parent().parent().find(".selected").append(newItem(ui.item));
      $(this).val("");
      return false;
    },
    focus: function(event, ui) {
      event.preventDefault();
    }
  });

  $(".selected").on("click", ".btn-close", function() {
    var id = $(this).parent().data("id");
    $(this).parent().remove();
    var sel = $("#city").val().split(",");
    sel = sel.splice(sel.indexOf(id), 1);
    $("#city").val(sel.join(","));
  });
});
```

The example uses the JSFiddle options to Echo back JSON data Posted to it. You will want to use your own `url` and `data`. I also setup some basinc exmaple items based on your post.

When the User types in a option, `wash`, they get options they can select. When they click on a selection a new item is created.

```
<span class="selected-item" data-id="56">Washington<span class="btn-close"></span></span>
```

This element is appended to the `.selected` element. This help prevent the user from entering `dasdsad`, this would return no results, and they cannot select anything.

If the User decides to remove a previously selected item, they click the `x` and it is removed. Behind the scene, as they make selections, the value of `#city` is updated to a list of IDs, `56,45`. When the User removes an item, the list is updated, and that entry is removed. This is done by converting the list into an Array and using Splice to remove the matching element.